# Guardar fichero con datos QLineEdit usando getSaveFileName

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

Estoy escribiendo una aplicación usando `pyqt4` y `python 3`. La entrada de datos es mediante `QLineEdit`, principalmente, y `QTextEdit`, se opera con los datos y se muestran los resultados en otros `QLineEdit`. Sobre el monitor funciona bien. Ahora quiero guardar estos datos para poder acceder a ellos en otra sesión.

El problema es que aún viendo multitud de ejemplos en la web soy incapaz de guardar los datos en un fichero. A lo más que he llegado a sido a guardar un fichero vacío.

Escribo a continuación un resumen de lo que he escrito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La ventana está creada con `QtDesigner`. Tras convertir el fichero `ui` a `py` escribo el código en `Python`. Este es un resumen:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import locale

from qtdesigner.cierzo_B import *

from classes.FEM_2131_2132.chapter_2.loads_A import AdditionalLoads

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.wind_speed_travelling_ms = self.ui.lineEditTravellingSpeed_ms
        self.wind_speed_travelling_kmh = self.ui.lineEditTravellingSpeed_kmh
        ...
        # Wind speed travelling m/s to km/h
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.lineEditTravellingSpeed_ms,
                               QtCore.SIGNAL('editingFinished()'),
                               self.wind_speed_travelling_ms2kmh)
        # Wind speed travelling km/h to m/s
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.lineEditTravellingSpeed_kmh,
                               QtCore.SIGNAL('editingFinished()'),
                               self.wind_speed_travelling_kmh2ms)
        ...
        # Save project
        QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonSaveProject, 
                        QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.save_project)
        ...

    def basic_pressure(self):

        vs_ms = float(self.wind_speed_in_service_ms.text())
        basic_press = self.wind_load.aerodynamic_wind_pressure(vs_ms)
        return basic_press

    def wind_speed_travelling_ms2kmh(self):

        vs_ms = float(self.wind_speed_travelling_ms.text())
        vs_kmh = int(3.6 * vs_ms)

        self.ui.lineEditTravellingSpeed_kmh.setText(str(vs_kmh))

        wind_pressure = self.wind_load.aerodynamic_wind_pressure(vs_ms)
        wind_pressure_ = locale.format('%.2f', wind_pressure)

        self.ui.lineEditTravellingPressure.setText(str(wind_pressure_))

        basic_pressure = self.basic_pressure()
        ratio = wind_pressure / basic_pressure
        ratio_ = locale.format('%.3f', ratio)

        self.ui.lineEditTravellingRatio.setText(str(ratio_))

    def wind_speed_travelling_kmh2ms(self):

        vs_kmh = float(self.wind_speed_travelling_kmh.text())
        vs_ms = int(vs_kmh / 3.6)

        self.ui.lineEditTravellingSpeed_ms.setText(str(vs_ms))

        wind_pressure = self.wind_load.aerodynamic_wind_pressure(vs_ms)
        wind_pressure_ = locale.format('%.2f', wind_pressure)

        self.ui.lineEditTravellingPressure.setText(str(wind_pressure_))

        basic_pressure = self.basic_pressure()
        ratio = wind_pressure / basic_pressure
        ratio_ = locale.format('%.3f', ratio)
    ...
```

En el método que creo para guardar los datos es donde tengo el problema.

```
def save_project(self):
    name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save file")
    f = open(name, 'w')
```

A partir de aquí no he conseguido guardar los datos en el fichero que se crea.

¿Me podeís indicar un ejemplo de cómo guardar los datos de los `QLineEdit` y `QTextEdit`en un fichero? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se exactamente donde tienes el problema pero simplemente debes obtener el texto de tus **`QLineEdit`** mediante el método `text()`.

En el caso de los **`QTextEdit`** va a depender de como quieras guardar el texto, dado que aceptan texto enriquecido. Si quieres guardarlo como texto plano usa el método `toPlainText`.

Posteriormente abres el archivo usando la ruta que retorna `QtGui.QFileDialog().getSaveFileName` y guardas el contenido. Usa la sentencia `with` (protocolo de manejador de contexto) para que el archivo se cierre correctamente y de forma automática.

Este es un ejemplo funcional que permite guardar el contenido de un LineEdit y de un TextEdit en un archivo de texto:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Guardar contenido")

        self.line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.text_edit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.save_button = QtGui.QPushButton(text='Guardar', parent=self)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel(text="QLineEdit"))
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel(text="QTextEdit"))
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.save_button)

        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.save_project)

        self.show()


    def save_project(self):
        name = QtGui.QFileDialog().getSaveFileName(self,
                                                   "Title",
                                                   "",
                                                   "Plain text file (*.txt)")
        with open(name, 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.line_edit.text() + "\n")
            f.write(self.text_edit.toPlainText())


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

No dices nada sobre la estructura que ha de tener el archivo o la codificación que quieres. El código anterior se limita a guardar el `QString` obtenido de ambos widgets separados por un salto de línea, si necesitas algo más específico aporta más datos.

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla, probaré lo que dices. El objetivo del fichero guardado es poder hacer una lectura  en una sesión posterior y visualizar los datos de nuevo en la pantalla. La estructura del fichero me basta con que sea lo suficientemente simple como para abrirla con `getOpenFileName`.